# Locate long file paths on external drive with terminal

Tags: terminal, finder, hard-drive, path, disk-format

I need to move a large volume to a new raid server that's PC formatted. However I have a couple paths and filenames that are interrupting this process.

I would just like to know how to use the terminal to:

1. Locate the targeted external drive
2. Then search that drive for paths/files that are over 130 characters

Can anyone help?

I know how to search for long paths find " . -type f -name '?????...*' ", just not sure how to target my external drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The external drive is mounted under `/Volumes`, run `ls /Volumes` to see the exact name.

Afterwards you can use

```
find /Volumes/NAME-FROM-ABOVE -print |
    while read line; do [[ ${#line} -gt 130 ]] && echo $line; done
```

to list all files where path and filename combined are longer than 130 characters.

PS: This will not work for file/path names containing new lines and similar stuff (which usually isn't a problem)
PPS: If your volume name contains spaces you need to wrap it in `""` -> `find "/Volumes/LaCie - BRYT" -print ...`

Comment: So my volume I'm wanting to target is 'LaCie - BRYT' but I think the name of the volume is messing with my print. I'm getting a return of "unknown primary or operator".

Comment: See edit. But go with Allan's solution for the whole thing, it's much nicer, slightly faster and will also work for edge cases like file names with new line characters

Comment: Ok got it! I was able to run 
find "/Volumes/LaCie - BYRT" -print | while read line; do [[ ${#line} -gt 130 ]] && echo $line; done
Which printed a lot. 
Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 4):

The following command will print out all files that have more than 130 characters

```
find -E . -type f -regex '.*[^/]{130}'
```

The Terminal (bash) command to list the disks attached to the system is `diskutil`.  The command `diskutil list` will output all disks - just select the identifier that matches your external device.

For example:

```
/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS FreeAgent Go            499.8 GB   disk3s2
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS My Passport for Mac     999.8 GB   disk4s2
```

`disk0`, `disk1`, and `disk2` are in a CoreStorage volume.  `disk3` and `disk4` are my external drivers

To access the drive (assuming it's mounted), look in the `/Volumes` directory for the appropriate mount point.

Assuming you wanted to search "My Passport for Mac" you would enter the command:

```
find -E /Volumes/My\ Passport\ for\ Mac/ -type f -regex '.*[^/]{130}'
```

Comment: Standard `find` doesn't support `-regextype`, unfortunately.

Comment: @patrix - you're right...I'm on ssh session to a different machine so of course, when I tested, it worked.  Duh...

Comment: But `-E` works -> `find -E . -type f -regex '.*[^/]{130}'` :-)

Comment: I was just reading the man page on `-E` when your comment came in.  Unfortunately, I don't have any files that long to *really* test it out with.  Thx!

Comment: So if my identifier is "disk3s2" how would I write it (sorry very noob).

Comment: Like this: 'find -disk3s2 . type f -regex '.*[^/]{130}'

Comment: To clarify, you want to find all files on an external disk longer than 130 chars?  Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that's my objective. the dive name is LaCie - BIRK and I believe is messing with the command. But I could be wrong, I'm just far too new to know.